# Функция вывода дерева ничего не возвращает

Tags: дерево, php

Есть массив, который нужно вывести в виде дерева, но почему-то функция вывода ничего не возвращает. Вот массив (упрощенный вариант):

```
$tree = array(0 => array('id' => 2013, 'parent_id' => null, 'name' => 2013),
              1 => array('id' => 07.2013, 'parent_id' => 2013, 'name' => 'Июль'),
              2 => array('id' => 06.2013, 'parent_id' => 2013, 'name' => 'Июнь')
            );
```

Вот функция вывода этого массива в виде дерева:

```
function build_tree($tree, $parent_id)
{
    if (is_array($tree) && isset($tree[$parent_id])) {
        $tree_date = "<ul>";
        foreach ($tree[$parent_id] as $tr) {
           $tree_date .= "<li>$tr[name]";
           $tree_date .=  build_tree($tree, $tr['id']);
           $tree_date .= "</li>";
        }
        $tree_date .= "</ul>";
    } else
        return false;
    return $tree_date;
}
echo build_tree($tree, null);
```

Надо, чтобы получилось что-то типа:

```
<ul>
<li>
    2013
    <ul>
        <li>Июнь</li>
        <li>Июль</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $tree[$parent_id]

тут вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу массива "2013", хотя у вас в массиве только (0=> , 1=> , 2=>)

Как вариант, вам нужно с начало найти элемент `$tree[$i]['id'] == $parent_id`

Например:

```
$parent_id = '2013';
$parent_ind = -1;
if (is_array($tree))
{
    foreach ($tree as $key => $dd)
    {
        if ($dd['id'] == $parent_id)
        {
            $parent_ind = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if ($parent_ind >= 0)
{
    // тут использовать и обращаться $tree[$parent_ind]
}
```

И вообще, в id, если вы храните через точку, то лучше храните в строке

Comment: Если честно, я не понял. Как это будет выглядеть все вместе?